# mouseover event not firing on child elements of a button

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I have a  element which contains an  element. I've found that in Internet Explorer and Firefox, the mouseover event doesn't fire when I move over the  element inside the button. In Chrome it does. Which browser(s) is behaving correctly and where might I go to report the bug? (this might not be the correct place to ask the question)

```
<button><img id="TheImage" src="Images/Action.gif" /></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.getElementById("TheImage").addEventListener("mouseover",     function(event) {
            console.log(event);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the event to fire and it seems like it should since that's the behavior on every other parent element.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to bug in FF:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2662
Though it should works good in IE.